# Model Driven / Reactive Forms: Auto mapping from Model to FormGroup ?

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

is there a way to automatically create a FormGroup from a Model?
If i have a Model with multiple Properties:

Model: Person

```
firstName: string,
lastName: string,
street: string
country: string
....
```

and i want to create a simple FormGroup out of it:

Form: FormGroup

```
firstName: FormControl,
lastName: FormControl,
street: FormControl,
country: FormControl
....
```

It seems to 'dirty' to me, to explicitly define for each property in the Model a FormControl / FormGroup / FormArray:

```
formBuilder.group({
  firstName: person.firstName,
  lastName: person.lastName,
  street: person.street,
  country: person.country,
  ...
});
```

Each time the API from the Backend changes i have to adjust the model AND the form mapping.
Is there some kind of generator which helps me to automate the mapping / creation of a FormGroup ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but I use a pattern of creating models that have two-way mappers (from server JSON, to server JSON). When you service fetches the model it maps to the client side format. Your components & forms always see this consistent interface. When you save the service can map it back. This is useful if the API has some clumsy or bad structure. If you add a field you still have to edit the component & models though.

Comment: Check this article: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-reactive-forms
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rbjwcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

```
formBuilder.group({});

person.forEach(
        (prop) => {
            formBuilder.addControl(prop , new FormControl(person[prop], Validators.compose([ Validators.required])));
        }
    );
```

Not a complete solution, because validators will change for each property certainly.